# how to get/trace asp.net outgoing response text

Tags: asp.net, stream, response

my server seems to be sometimes returning wrong html to webclients

im using asp.net 4 with VS 2012. debugging on IIS Express.

in order to debug this issue, id like to trace the html that asp.net is sending

in the `Global_asax_PreRequestHandlerExecute` i can access the response code and status, but cant seem to find the body html

i tried to read the `OutputStream` like this:

```
Dim ms = New MemoryStream
CurContext.Response.OutputStream.CopyTo(ms)
Dim sr = New StreamReader(ms)
Dim rtext = sr.ReadToEnd
```

but that throws a `NotSupportedException` `Stream does not support reading.`

any ideas?

thanks a lot

**EDIT**

i now tested this for sure

i have a label on the page with the following attributes

```
<asp:label id="l" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="X-Large" BackColor="Pink"/>
```

when displayed in the browser it shows just fine, as follows:

```
<span id="C1_FormView1_l" style="background-color:Pink;font-size:X-Large;font-weight:bold;">Processed</span>
```

but when downloaded with webclient i get

```
<span id="C1_FormView1_l"><b><font size="6">Processed</font></b></span>
```

why is the backcolor lost? and btw, why doesn't it use the more modern `style` attribute instead of adding `b` and `font`

if i could read the ResponseStream i would at least know WHERE it gets lost, even that i dont know now.

thank you very much

P.S. if .net 4.5 is better for this, then i might consider changing the target framework

Comment: anybody got any ideas for me? its really important for me... thanks!

Comment: What version of .net are you using? Can you give more examples of the "wrong html" and what you are expecting to see?

Comment: hi i updated the post with the relevant info. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this does not answer my original question technically, but it does solve the issue i was having

the problem was that the html wasnt rendering correctly

i now remembered that aspx has adaptive rendering, so i fgured the useragent used in the request might be to blame

i changed my code to:

```
 Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(MailUrl)
 myReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1"
 Dim resp As HttpWebResponse = myReq.GetResponse
 Dim stream = resp.GetResponseStream
 Dim rdr = New StreamReader(stream)
 Dim BodyText = rdr.ReadToEnd
```

and now the html is rendering in correct modern Html5/Css3 markup

i appreciate your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the HTML (and modify it) by overriding Render on the page / site master.

```
        protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms))
                {
                    HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                    base.Render(tw);
                    tw.Flush();
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ms))
                    {
                        string yourHTML = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        // do stuff with yourHTML
                        Response.Write(yourHTML);
                        sr.Close();
                        tw.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

in vb

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
            Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(ms)
                Dim tw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
                MyBase.Render(tw)
                tw.Flush()
                ms.Position = 0
                Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(ms)
                    Dim yourHTML As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
                    'do stuff with yourHTML'
                    Response.Write(yourHTML)
                    sr.Close()
                    tw.Dispose()

                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: hi. the idea looks pretty good. but it throws `RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();`. this is because i use notation like `$("#<%=lblMain.clientid %>")` in my jquery. anyway to overcome this?

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. You initially asked about how to get outgoing response, which I showed. Now you are talking about validators and jquery. Should you open a new question ?

Comment: what im saying is that the code you sent does not work. the reason your code snippet doesn't work is because in my page i have inline code in the jquery. its not as if there's a bug with my jq or anything, its just that ` MyBase.Render(tw)` obviously cannot render what standard aspx could.

Comment: Can you show where you are using the RegisterForEventValidation? Also, you can use jquery like that without the RegisterForEventValidation.

Comment: im not using RegisterForEventValidation as far as i am aware. its just that the debugger crashes on that line with this error. maybe some internal code is calling it?