# How do I send output of ASP.NET webforms site to a string/email ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

There is a site for sales where the end user prints out the details for the customer and that already contains all the information/HTML/ASPX page.

They want me to now send this HTML to the user as an EMAIL...

So rather than recreate each piece bit by bit.. is there someway to tell the server when it is done rendering the page to send the output to a string perhaps? Then I could have a function that takes that HTML in the string and creates an email with it.?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999665/how-to-get-trace-asp-net-outgoing-response-text) shows how you can get the HTML that is about to be sent to the browser.

Comment: Might be ugly as mentioned below but Ill give this a try and see what happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't send the exact HTML of your page as an email, as the results likely won't be good when viewing in their email client. Instead, custom generate the body of your email, and send it using the functionality in the `System.Net.Mail` namespace. Probably start with [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) and [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

A page is usually formatted for a large browser window and contains much extra stuff like JavaScript and navigation elements. And it often refers to external CSS files for formatting. Consider that this wouldn't look very good when viewed in an email client. So yes, better to hand code or at least selectively get the HTML of your relevant Controls and send that rather than sending the HTML for the entire page.

Comment: Show there is no easy way to take the output seen on the browser and have that same look appear in a users email? In otherwords I will need to do it all by hand?